# Search in Hashmap and return value

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to search in a hashmap in a grails application that looks like this

```
 [[name: asset1, ips:[10.1.1.1, 10.1.2.3]], [name: asset2, ips:[192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3]], [name: asset3, [ips: 1.2.3.4, 2.3.4.5, 3.4.5.6]]]
```

Now I want to search for an ip address (e.g. 10.1.1.1) and want to return the name of the corresponding asset (e.g. asset1).

I have no idea how to do this in grails.

I have tried with findAll(), but have no idea if this is the right direction.

```
 asset = assetList.findAll{it.value == ipAddress}.each {name << it.key}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
asset = assetList.findAll{ ipAddress in it.ips}.name
```